# Conditional expectation of two independent RV

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, expected-value, conditional-expectation

The expectation of the product of two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ is the product of the expectations:
\begin{align}
E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)
\end{align}
Let's add another random variable $Z$ in the mix, do we have the following equality:
\begin{align}
E(XY \vert Z) = E(X \vert Z)E(Y \vert Z)
\end{align}

Comment: $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$ is, generally speaking, not true.

Comment: Yes of course, I forgot to write the independent hypothesis, just edited the post

Comment: The short answer is: you need conditional independence of $X$ and $Y$ given $Z$. Independence of $X$ and $Y$ is insufficient.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/184933/80704

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not true (in general). For example, let's say, $X,Y$ are the two different coin tosses. And, $Z$ is the number of heads you get after these tosses. Apparently, $X$ and $Y$ are independent; but given $Z$, they're not. Also, independence means $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$, but having it holds doesn't mean they're independent.